# Groovy - Wait on list of promises

Tags: grails, groovy, promise

I have several promises in my program and I need to **wait on all** of them simulateneously before moving on. For `Grails`, I found the following example:

```
def p1 = task { 2 * 2 }
def p2 = task { 4 * 4 }
def p3 = task { 8 * 8 }
assert [4,16,64] == waitAll(p1, p2, p3)
```

I know Grails is heavily relying on [GPars](http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/index.html), but I cannot find the reference to `waitAll` anywhere in there. `Grails` also supports  [PromiseList](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/api/grails/async/PromiseList.html), which I cannot find in `Groovy` or `GPars` either. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what Grails version?

Comment: @saw303 I'm not interested in `Grails`. This is just how I came across the `waitAll` and `PromiseList`. I require the same functionality directly in a `Groovy` application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

waitAll is a Grails specific static method from [Promises](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/api/grails/async/Promises.html) class. It internally built on GPars [whenAllBound](http://gpars.org/SNAPSHOT/javadoc/groovyx/gpars/dataflow/Dataflow.html#whenAllBound-java.util.List-groovy.lang.Closure-) method which you can use for your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **defectus** and **Feras Odeh**, I could figure out the correct way of doing it with [whenAllBound](http://gpars.org/SNAPSHOT/javadoc/groovyx/gpars/dataflow/Dataflow.html#whenAllBound-java.util.List-groovy.lang.Closure-). Just to save everyone else a bit of time, here is a working code example:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflow.task
import static groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflow.whenAllBound;

def p1 = task { 2 * 2 }
def p2 = task { 4 * 4 }
def p3 = task { 8 * 8 }
def total = whenAllBound(p1, p2, p3, { List<?> values -> values })
assertTrue([4,16,64] == total.get())
```

`whenAllBound` expects a closure that is called **with the results** of all promises. I simply collect them and return them as they are. Also, `whenAllBound` **returns a promise** itself, so you will need to call the `.get()` method on it (see assertion statement).

Answer (score 1):

The truth it's in the source code.

```
import groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Dataflow

def <T> List<groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Promise<T>> toGparsPromises(List<Promise<T>> promises) {
    final List<groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Promise<T>> dataflowPromises = promises.collect() { it -> (groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Promise<T>)((GparsPromise<T>)it).internalPromise }
    dataflowPromises
}

private static Closure<List<?>> originalValuesClosure = { List<?> values -> values }

def <T> List<T> waitAll(List<Promise<T>> promises) {
    final groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Promise<List<T>> promise = (groovyx.gpars.dataflow.Promise<List<T>>)Dataflow.whenAllBound(toGparsPromises(promises), originalValuesClosure)
    return promise.get()
}
```

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-async/src/main/groovy/org/grails/async/factory/gpars/GparsPromiseFactory.groovy